# Troubleshooting "The controller for URI is not callable" error

Tags: symfony, routes

I'm working on **Symfony 2.3** and I declared a new **route** and new **controller**, but when I call this controller from the browser I get this error:

`The controller for URI "/user/1" is not callable. in /dev.mydomain.org/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php at line 82`

This is my simple **route** configuration:

```yaml
user_homepage:
    pattern:  /user
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:index }
    
user_show:
    pattern:  /user/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:show }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

And this is my very simple **controller**:

```php
public function showUserAction($id)
{        
    return $this->render('UserBundle:Default:show.html.twig', array());
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The logical name `UserBundle:Default:show` refers to `UserBunde\Controller\DefaultController::showAction` you have a method called `showUserAction`.

Either change the method name to `showAction` or change the logical name to `UserBundle:Default:showUser`.

Comment: The name of the vendor I have omitted on purpose. Anyway it works now.
Thank you very much. Today has been a hard day's work.

Comment: +1 and facepalm, I forgot the Action part of my function name.

Answer (score 23):

Although not relevant to the example given, this error can also be caused if the controller Action is not public

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  Id changed my mind on which method was being called via ajax and the other method was private which caused this error.  had me stumped for a good 15 mins.  Thank you  =)

Answer (score 4):

You're defining your controller function as `showUserAction` while in the definition your saying it is `show[Action]`.

Either change your route configuration

```
user_show:
    pattern:  /user/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Default:showUser }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

or change your controller signature

```
public function showAction($id)
{
```

See if this helps

Answer (score 3):

After big search, this worked for me:

1.- Create CRUDController

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/CRUDController.php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Inter\PimeBundle\Entity\Empresa;

class CRUDController extends Controller
{
    public function publicarAction($id)
    {
       //code here...
    }
}
```

2.- Create the service

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    ebtity.admin.service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Admin\EntityAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: group, label: label }
        arguments:
            - NULL
            - Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Entity
            - AcmeDemoBundle:EntityAdmin
```

3.- Create the template for the action button

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list__action_publicar.html.twig #}

<a class="btn btn-sm" href="{{ admin.generateObjectUrl('publicar', object) }}">Publicar</a>
```

4.- Configure route

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Admin/EntityAdmin.php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Admin;

// ...

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class EntityAdmin extends Admin
{
     // ...

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name')
            ->add('engine')
            ->add('rescueEngine')
            ->add('createdAt')
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'publicar' => array(
                        'template' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:CRUD:list__action_publicar.html.twig'
                    )
                )
            ));
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection
                ->add('publicar', 
                    $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/publicar',
                    array('_controller' => 'AcmeDemoBundle:CRUD:publicar')    
                );
    }
}
```

5.- Clear cache

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Not the case here. But there is another related issue:

If you forget the 'Action' suffix all will work. But when you realized that you forget the suffix and then add it ... surprise! Same error as the OP.

The problem here is about caching

Symfony creates two file for caching urls:

- AppDevUrlGenerator.php
- AppDevUrlMatcher.php

If you change your action name (i.e. adding 'Action' suffix) then that cache info is obsolete.

**Solution**

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, if your controller is defined as a service, e.g. (in YAML):

```
services:
    user.default:
        class: \UserBundle\DefaultController
```

And your route uses this controller service:

```
user_show:
    pattern:  /user/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: user.default:showUserAction }
    requirements:
        id:  \d+
```

Then it's necessary to name the action method *in full* including the `Action` suffix, otherwise you will get the "controller ... is not callable" error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was using ***symfony*** 2.

Prior version of symfony maintain method naming convention. Method suffix should contain ***Action*** word.

example:

in route yml file the method definition was

```
docudex_report_make_authorization:
pattern:  /make-authorization
defaults: { _controller: DocudexReportBundle:Default:makeAuthorization }
```

and in the controller the method was

```
public function makeAuthorization(){}
```

therefore i was getting the error.

After changing the method name to `public function makeAuthorizationAction` it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my experience & how I solved it:

I was importing one bundle in an application whose routes were defined using annotations and they were importing fine in application too by using:

```
auth_bundle_routes:
  # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
  resource: '@XyzAuthBundle/Controller/'
  type:     annotation
```

But since my bundle controllers were defined using services, Symfony was showing error:

> The controller for URI "/facebook/request-code" is not callable.
>   Controller Xyz\AuthBundle\Controller\FacebookController" has required
>   constructor arguments and does not exist in the container. Did you
>   forget to define such a service?

I updated my bundle for routing to use routing.yaml file over annotations and referring to controllers as `service::method` syntax and then this error is gone.

```
xyz_auth.facebook_request_code:
  path: /facebook/request-code
  controller: xyz_auth.controller.facebook_controller::requestCode
```

Bundle routes must be imported using

```
auth_bundle_routes:
  resource: '@XyzAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml'
```

Hope this will save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue could happen if your env uses `.env.local.php` and new changes are added to env files without running `composer dump-env`

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons for this error is that you missed to add the word "Action" after the controller's method name. If you think that your routing is OK, check the method name.