# Vich UploadedFile, FOSUserBundle and Events

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8, vichuploaderbundle

I added a VichImageType field on edit profile twig template...so im trying to check image dimensions using vich_uploader.pre_upload as Event.

In my class i got the image properties and if their dimensions arent bigger enough i tried to stop propagation and flashed a message to the twig template but, i dont know why, the event keeps propagating and redirects to fos_user_profile_show showing the image setup. Also, i tried to redirect again to fos_user_profile_edit but i cant use $event because "Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Event" doesnt implement setController(). How can achieve this?

This is the method of the Listener class:

```
namespace BackendBundle\EventListener;

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Event\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class ComprobarDimensionesDeImagen
{

private $requestStack;
private $router;

public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, RouterInterface $router)
{
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function onVichUploaderPreUpload(Event $event)
{
    $object = $event->getObject();
    $mapping = $event->getMapping();

    $imagen = getimagesize($object->getImageFile());

    if (250 > $imagen[0] || 250 > imagen[1]) {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $event->stopPropagation();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('error', "Minimum dimensions: 250x250 \n");

        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_profile_edit');
        /*
         * Testing different methods of redirect
         * 
         * $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
         * $event->setResponse($response);
         */

        $event->setController(function() use ($request) {
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        });            
    }
}
}
```

When i edit the profile again, I can see the flash message and the image setup in VichImageType field (i didnt expect that stopping propagation). Any help will be very welcome.

**SOLVED**: Just using @Assert\Image in my Entity class did the validation. No service neither listener needed

Answer (score 1):

The argument for ->setController must be a [callable](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/FilterControllerEvent.html#method_setController) . In your case, the function you pass as an argument returns an object of type Response. In order to be callable, the method should have the suffix `Action`. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942735/troubleshooting-the-controller-for-uri-is-not-callable-error).

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it. Now I know that $event parameter is not callable but its the object returned by the event `vich_uploader.pre_upload`. How can i redirect to fos_user_profile_edit to workaround that event keeps propagating or throw a form exception?

Comment: No, I was talking about the function() you pass as the argument for `$event->setController()` . as stated in the documentation, this argument must be a callable, which I believe your anonymous function (or what it returns) is not.

Comment: OK, thank you. Anyway, my approaching to the problem was wrong. I just needed to use Image constraint with Assert in my entity class linked to the Form instead of the complicated path I chose. That way Form's validation do the thing. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Yep, true, best way to do it. Good luck with your project!